# have an error when i try import my component in react native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I got an error when i try import my component.
here is text of error  :
"element type is invalid expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function".

Main file index.android.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View
} from 'react-native';

import {Text2} from './components/Text2';

class p001_lesson extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text2/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('p001_lesson', () => p001_lesson);
```

```
second file Text2.js

<pre>
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    Text,
} from 'react-native';


class Text2 extends Component {
    render() {
        return <Text>some text here</Text>
    }
}
```

How i can fix my import? Sorry for my English :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you export your Text2 component?

If you exported it as a default export, like this:

```
export default Text2
```

then you have to import it like this:

```
import Text2 from './components/Text2'
```

Comment: i dont write export, ty

Answer (score 0):

exporting your components will can solve the problem,
expect export default you can use only export

```
export Text2
```

Then you should import it like this:

```
import { Text2 } from './components/Text2';
```