# React Native, can't import custom components

Tags: react-native

I'm new to React Native and I am currently trying to create a custom component called OpButton. It's just a button so that I can try to import and export components. However everytime I try to import it, I keep getting errors like "Imvariant Violation" and I have no idea how to fix it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Alert } from 'react-native';
export default class OpButton extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Button
       onPress={() => Alert.alert("Hello World")}
       title= "Hello World"
       color="#841584"
       accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
      />
   );
 }
}
```

My button.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { OpButton } from "./src/components/button";
 export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
   return (
    <OpButton></OpButton>
  );
 }
}
```

My App.js

Comment: Try `import OpButton from "./src/components/button";` instead

Comment: yeah, `import OpButton` without curly braces it should work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [have an error when i try import my component in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41643995/have-an-error-when-i-try-import-my-component-in-react-native)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `import OpButton from "./src/components/button"`

Curly braces are used on an import when the file you're importing from is exporting the variable as a const (`export const OpButton . . .`) but when you `export default OpButton`, then when you import from that file without curly braces, you always import the default thing, no matter what you call it in your import. So you could do `import AnyNameYouWant from "./src/components/button"` and then use `<AnyNameYouWant />` in your `App.js`

Answer (score 1):

Though the answer was already accepted. I want to make you clear on few things. You need to understand two things here

1. export default class
2. export class

When you use export default class which means that component is exported by default and you can import that like below

```
  import component from ‘./Component’;
```

When you use export class without default, you can import that like below

```
  import {component, component1} from ‘./Component’;
```

Comment: There's no div or span in React Native

Comment: Sorry I don’t no much in React-native. Thanks for pointing that